# android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" is not working as it should be

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, window-soft-input-mode

Even though this problem has many solutions in stackoverflow, I could not solve my problem.
I have two edit texts in the screen, one  on top, another is attached to bottom of the screen.
Whenever I click on bottom edit text, softkey board comes over it. I already played with windowSoftInputMode.

I dont want other content of the screen to scroll up when I click on my bottom edittext.

This is my xml layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/phone_number_edit_text_compose"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/select_contact"
   android:background="@drawable/phone_edittext_background_selector"
   android:ems="10"
   android:hint="@string/phone_edittext_hint"
   android:inputType="phone"
   android:paddingBottom="12dp"
   android:paddingLeft="8dp"
   android:paddingTop="12dp"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
   android:textColor="@color/white" />

<ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/selectcontact_compose"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phone_number_edit_text_compose"
 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/phone_number_edit_text_compose"
 android:background="@drawable/select_contact_background_selector"
 android:contentDescription="@string/select_contact_content_description"
 android:src="@drawable/select_contact_selector"
 android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
 android:paddingLeft="8dp"
 android:paddingRight="8dp"/>

<View
     android:id="@+id/view1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="2px"
     android:layout_below="@id/phone_number_edit_text_compose"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/redial_screen_distance_between_views"
     android:background="@drawable/separator" />

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/repetition_layout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:onClick="RepetitionLayoutClickListener"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/redial_screen_distance_between_views"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/redial_screen_distance_between_views" 
   android:background="@drawable/repetition_layout_background_selector"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/repetition_textview"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/repetition"
  android:textColor="@color/green"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/repetition_spinner"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@null"
  android:clickable="false"
  android:popupBackground="@color/dark_background" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
     android:id="@+id/view2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="2px"
     android:layout_below="@id/repetition_layout"
     android:background="@drawable/separator" />

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/redial_screen_distance_between_views"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/redial_screen_distance_between_views" 
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:id="@+id/date_layout">

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/d"
   android:textColor="@color/green"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/date_textview"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/a"
   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
<View
     android:id="@+id/view3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="2px"
     android:layout_below="@id/date_layout"
     android:background="@drawable/separator" />

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/view3"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/redial_screen_distance_between_views"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/redial_screen_distance_between_views" 
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:id="@+id/time_layout">

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/t"
   android:textColor="@color/green"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/time_textview"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/b"
   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/compose_layout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1">

<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/compose_message_background"
   android:hint="@string/compose_message_hint"
   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:paddingRight="5dp"
   android:paddingTop="12dp"
   android:paddingBottom="12dp"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1" >

</EditText>

<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/send_button_background"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send_now" 
   android:paddingRight="8dp"
   android:paddingLeft="8dp"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this my manifest xml.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.task.SmsScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      >        
    </activity>
```

Comment: Use this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"

Comment: try  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: @PiyushGupta I played with all combination Piyush... This scrolls all other content of the screen up.

Comment: @RethinavelPillai This scrolls all other content of the screen up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your outer Linear Layout and place everything inside a Relative Layout. And align your bottom edit text to bottom of the layout by making alignParentBottom true.
And main thing "Dont do anything to the android:windowSoftInputMode." Delete that line from manifest file.
Let android take default.

Comment: This worked for me, although I really don't know why it would work with a Relative but not with a Linear

Comment: why should place it inside relative layout?

Comment: @zihadrizkyef When the keyboard opens your root container becomes small but edit text is aligned to the bottom it will also move up with the parent

Comment: @Praveena why I can't use LinearLayout? why should RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 4):

You did not say which version of android are you compiling for and which version are you running on.
But check if you perhaps use fullscreen option set by about android:windowFullscreen attribute or by setting FLAG_FULSCREEN. This prevents adjusrResize option to wrok properly on newer APIs. It works for API 10 (2.3.5).

Comment: Thanks. I was using SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN for SystemUiVisibility which was causing adjustResize to not work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<activity
        android:name="com.task.SmsScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      >        
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you but I dont want other content of the screen to scroll up when I click on my bottom edittext.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of hassle and reading all the stackoverflow solutions I came up with my own. It worked for me. 
I had to use scrollview only then it adjusts itself in the tiny space by shrinking the view. Without scrollview I had to use the Outermost LinearLayout with layout_gravity:bottom. But with this settings all the elements drops at the bottom of the Screen. if used layout_margintop or layout_marginbottom then when keyboard pops up some of the textview or edittextview thrown away out of the screen .. Grrrrrrrrrrr....

So, finally I found this solution hope it may solve some of your problem.

in Manifest.xml

`<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation">`

In Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/love_bg_red_10"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtvwYourName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@layout/border_header"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Your Name"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edttxtFistName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@layout/border_edittextview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Type your name here"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:tag="edttxtFistName"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtvwFavPersonName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@layout/border_header"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Name of your favorite person"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edttxtLastName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@layout/border_edittextview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Type your favorite person&apos;s name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:tag="edttxtLastName"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@layout/button_background"
            android:text="Calculate"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

put a Linearlayout enclosing tag after scrollview.

Android really really awful .

### Device info

Devcie: Xperia Z
OS: JellyBean
[ Dont know how it will behave in older versions.]